# Error applying xmlParse to a html format cells in R dataframe with r-dplyr

Tags: r, xml, dplyr

I'm trying to extract certain values from a html string who is contained in the cells of a R data.frame in this form:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|          ID         |       DATE       |                             HTML_RES                            |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|      00000010       |    2020-02-01    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><RespuestaSVC11> ... |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|      00000011       |    2020-02-01    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><RespuestaSVC11> ... |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|      00000012       |    2020-02-01    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><RespuestaSVC11> ... |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|      00000013       |    2020-02-01    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><RespuestaSVC11> ... |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The html string look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<RespuestaSVC11>
    <Header>
        ...
    </Header>
    <Integrante>
        ...
    </Integrante>
    <GrupoCampos>
        <Campo>
            <Nombre>Accion</Nombre>
            <ExisteCampo>0</ExisteCampo>
            <Valor>CALIFICA</Valor>
        </Campo>
        <Campo>
            <Nombre>rp2</Nombre>
            <ExisteCampo>0</ExisteCampo>
            <Valor>813</Valor>
        </Campo>
        <Campo>
            <Nombre>explicacion</Nombre>
            <ExisteCampo>0</ExisteCampo>
            <Valor>El solicitante tiene un RP mayor o igual a 593.</Valor>
        </Campo>
    </GrupoCampos>
</RespuestaSVC11>
```

When I appy the xmlParse function to an individual cell, via base forms, the results are according to expectations:

```
# Translate HTML
library(XML)

# Scraping
score_xml <- xmlParse(df_raw_data$html_res[1], asText = TRUE)
score_root <- xmlRoot(score_xml)
score_child <- xmlChildren(score_root)

score_det <-  score_child[[3]]

score_res <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xmlChildren(score_det)[[1]])[[3]])
score_num <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xmlChildren(score_det)[[2]])[[3]])
score_txt <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(xmlChildren(score_det)[[3]])[[3]])
```

But, when I try to do this via r-dplyr function, I get the following error:

```
# Row manupulation
librery(tidyverse)

df_score <- df_raw_data%>%
  mutate(html_parse = xmlParse(html_res, asText = TRUE))
```

```
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Extra content at the end of the document
Error: 1: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document 2: Extra content at the end of the document
```

any suggestion?